# execv to .c prog that work with the same pipe

Tags: c, execv

I have to write a code that run fork.
The child is an another project that have the main that have to bo done.
I run the `execv()` function but it don't find the the path.
the child file is in other project in the same computer.

Second question: the `child` is my program. how to make it executable?

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int pipefd[2];
    pid_t cpid1; 
    char *checkRows[] = { "child", "-r", NULL };
    if (pipe(pipefd) == -1)
    {
        perror("pipe");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    cpid1 = fork();
    if (cpid1 == 0)
    { // child 1
        printf("after fork %d", cpid1);
        dup2(pipefd[1], 1); // redirect stdout to pipe
        close(pipefd[0]);
        execv("child",checkRows);
        perror("execc rows failed");
    }
    else if (cpid1 == -1)
    { // fork failed
        printf("error!");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    close(pipefd[1]);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

the child

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 3){
        printf("there is no arguments pass");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("In child");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: execv() does not use the PATH to find the executable. You'll have to specify the exact filename/pathname.

Comment: or use `execvp` where *p* **does stand** for PATH.

Comment: the path not Found   execvp rows failed: No such file or directory

Comment: Even with execvp it won't work if PATH is not set correctly.

Answer (score 1):

From execv(3):

```
 int
 execv(const char *path, char *const argv[]);

 The execv(), execvp(), and execvP() functions provide an array of point-
 ers to null-terminated strings that represent the argument list available
 to the new program.  The first argument, by convention, should point to
 the file name associated with the file being executed.  The array of
 pointers must be terminated by a NULL pointer.
```

And from execvp(3) (actually the same man page):

```
 int
 execvp(const char *file, char *const argv[]);

 The functions execlp(), execvp(), and execvP() will duplicate the actions
 of the shell in searching for an executable file if the specified file
 name does not contain a slash ``/'' character.  For execlp() and
 execvp(), search path is the path specified in the environment by
 ``PATH'' variable.  If this variable isn't specified, the default path is
 set according to the _PATH_DEFPATH definition in <paths.h>, which is set
 to ``/usr/bin:/bin''.  For execvP(), the search path is specified as an
 argument to the function.  In addition, certain errors are treated spe-
 cially.
```

That means that you can use

```
 execv("/absolute/patch/to/child",...)
```

As alternate solution you can use

```
 execvp("child",...)
```

with "/absolute/patch/to" added to PATH.

Note: Both calls are library calls provided by standard C library. The only syscall of "exec family" is execve().

Comment: Does this answer your question? Then please mark it as solution.